# Furigana with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kanji

I am trying to show furigana (small text helping for pronunciation) above kanji using Jetpack Compose.
I have searched on the Web but all tools are designed to be used with Java.

Comment: It seems there is something to do with Ruby. So my question would be how to include it with Jetpack Compose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Android Compose Furigana](https://github.com/mainrs/android-compose-furigana) to put furigana on text.

Here is how to use it:

1. Add dependency in Gradle build file

```
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.mainrs:android-compose-furigana:1.0.0'
    }
```

Or, in Gradle Kotlin DSL

```
    dependencies {
        implementation("com.github.mainrs:android-compose-furigana:1.0.0")
    }
```

2. Declare composable furigana text

```
    import net.zerotask.libraries.android.compose.furigana.TextData
    import net.zerotask.libraries.android.compose.furigana.TextWithReading
    
    @Composable
    internal fun Content(){
        val textContent = listOf(
            TextData(text = "これは")
            TextData(text = "漢字", rading = "かんじ")
            TextData(text = "です")
        )
        TextWithReading(textContent = textContent, showReadings = true)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Joel. It is much more better than my solution

Answer (score 0):

Author of the library here. There are still some shortcomings that I could not solve that probably involve tinkering around with `TextLayout`. Specifically, the text is not split at good positions. Compared to `Text`, which splits at positions that make sense grammatically.